# Replacement distribution for Arch Linux on Pi 1B

Tags: archlinux, pi-1

I have a Pi 1B and I am currently running [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/) on it.  [As they announced](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15721) the repositories for armv6 – and hence my device – have been shut down as of Feburary 2022.

Now I am looking for a replacement distro.  On x86 hardware I am using [Arch Linux](https://archlinux.org) and [NixOS](https://nixos.org).  So something similar to those is what I am looking for.  More concretely I ...

- need ssh in the base system as the device is headless
- want a minimal system (not a bunch of software in the base system, I will configure it myself)
- prefer rolling release distros over versioned distros

**What distros do exist that might fit these criteria and also support the Pi 1B (armv6)?**

Comment: Welcome. WRT "ssh in the base system as the device is headless" implies you want something with sshd installed so all you have to do is configure it to start (or else you want something with sshd already configured to start), which is slightly contra wanting "a minimal system" as "minimal" usually means you have to install and configure non-essential things. What rolling release distros are available for the Pi 1 is reasonably objective (but seems like somethiing that is easier solved with a quick online search).

Comment: WRT ssh, a further issue is that there are probably not *any* distros that ship with it configured to run out of the box, because this is a significant security problem -- Raspbian *used to do this* until Pis the world over were found being recruited into bot nets because they had `sshd` open with a default password that users commonly do not change.